# resubmit rejected iphone app

Tags: iphone

I made the changes indicated in rejection report, and ready to submit the app again. Do I

1. go through the add new app process again like the first time and fill out all the information, or
2. simply click "ready to upload binary" and upload the binary from Xcode - meaning other than uploading the fixed binary, there is nothing else to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you made changes to the binary then just upload a new one (option 2). If they only had you change app store data (description/screenshots) then you can even skip this, and just ask them to re-review in the resolution center.

Comment: The only change I made was to info.plist. Since that's part of the binary, I guess I just simply upload the binary again???